# IIS 7.5 log files not showing up

Tags: logging, iis-7.5, aem

I have IIS 7.5 on Windows 7 and enabled logging in IIS Manger.

I also, have installed Adobe AEM Dispatcher for load balancing and caching.  According to the Dispatcher documentation I put the following line in my disp_iis.ini file:

logfile=C:\inetpub\logs\dispatcher\dispatcher.log

But I do not get any log files.  I made sure my server is running and my publish  instance of AEM is running as well.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got my logs to appear by going into Internet Information Services(IIS) Manager.

On the left side under "connections" I picked my web site that I was using as a dispatcher.  On the right side I double clicked "logging."  In the "logging" dialog that appears I put C:\inetpub\logs\dispatcher for the directory. Notice that this path is the same as what I put in my disp_iss.ini file but without the file name.

It worked after that.